# After session expired not redirecting to login page in server but in local host it does

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, cpanel

I am using this

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login_success'])):  header("Location:index.php"); 

die();
endif;
```

It does work in local host but after i uploaded the site in server, when session expires it stays in the same page and not redirect to index or login page.

Comment: Please make sure there is no data output (not even a space character) before the header location line.

Comment: there is no space. the above code is exact same one i am using. and space should not be the problem i guess.

Comment: Enable errors reporting to see if there is info about headers already sent. It's possible that the server on localhost has output buffering enabled and the other one doesn't and that's why it doesn't work, because some html is already sent.

Comment: @Robert This might be the cause because i have a top.php file where my html header and nav bar are. and i started session start() function there. after that in every other pages i just include that top.php file and check login_success session. so basically after the session start there are some html and then the checking going on. so what might be the solution?

Comment: Are you working with a shared host? Do you have access to php.ini on the server? Can you turn on error reporting or check the log files?

Comment: You can try to add `ob_start();` at the beggining of the top.php file or where you have `session_start();`. See docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: ob_start(); does the trick. but i am wondering will it effect to any other thing and do i need to end ob anywhere. sry i am not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

Are  You sure you initialize **sessions** before that your code.

Try this at very top of script and let me know how it goes.

```
    //initialize session
    session_start();
    //set session
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_success']) || (trim($_SESSION['login_success']) == '')) {
            header("location: index.php");
            exit();
        }
// Your template file is included below
include_once 'template/top.php';
```

Comment: i have included top.php where i initialized session_start(); 
`include_once 'template/top.php';

if (!isset($_SESSION['login_success'])):  header("Location:index.php"); 

die();
endif;`

Comment: You will have to check if session is set first before including your template/top.php file. I have updated my answer to that effect. Put that code at the very top of your page

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if session is set first before including your template/top.php file. I have updated my answer to that effect. Put that code at the very top of your page –
Nancy Moore
Feb 16 at 8:49

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).